# Convert a string (as shortcut) to bytes in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have `minSize` and `maxSize` as settings for uploading files.
And I would like to make as simpler as possible the input of the file size as following `1KB` in lieu of `1000`.

I have written this code:

```
function convertFileSize(shortcut)
{
    var bytesArr = {
       'B' : 1,
       'KB': 1e+3, // 1 KB = 1e+3 B
       'MB': 1e+6, // 1 MB = 1e+6 B
       'GB': 1e+9, // 1 GB = 1e+9 B
       'TB': 1e+12 // 1 TB = 1e+12 B
    };
   var converted = null;
   $.map(bytesArr, function(val, symbol){
       var splitted = shortcut.split(' ');
       if( splitted.length == 2 && splitted[1] == symbol ){
           converted = splitted[0] * val;
       }
   });
   return converted;
}
```

Usage: `convertFileSize('1 KB') // output 1000`

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: I wonder if the conversion is correct.

Comment: 1 kb is not 1000 bytes. it's 1024 bytes

Comment: also if the input does not contain a whitespace it fails

Comment: @EliasSoares maybe not https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte 1024 bytes is a kibibyte according to that article. That being said I've always thought KB = 1024 B.
Maybe it's both... https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/4425/should-i-teach-that-1-kb-1024-bytes-or-1000-bytes

Comment: Yes, but when we deal with file size, we always talk about KiB (1024) not KB.

Comment: See this nice answer: https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/13850

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code I would finaly use (Binary prefix based):

```
convertFileSize(shortcut) {
    const bytesArr = {
        'B' : 1,
        'KB': 1024,
        'MB': 1.049e+6,
        'GB': 1.074e+9,
        'TB': 1.1e+12,
        'PB': 1.126e+15
    };
    var splitted = shortcut.split(' ');
    if( splitted.length == 2 ){
        const value = splitted[0],
               unit = splitted[1];
        return bytesArr[unit] ? value * bytesArr[unit] : null;
    }
    return null;
}
```